# Does bouncycastle jar support openjdk?

Tags: bouncycastle

I'm evaluating the bouncycastle for my project and want to know if it supports openjdk as well. I could not find this info on it's official website explicitly, but got the table maintaining the versions [here](https://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use it myself with openjdk all the time, and in general it should work with any Java implementation (bearing in mind there are different jars targeted at different java versions). It doesn't mean there can't be incompatibilities, we've run across a few over the years, but they are rare nowadays.

Comment: Thank You Peter. I also found out few of the issue logged and addressed for openjdk. So it seems that openjdk is supported platform.